# Tag "single-word-request" in ELL

Tags: discussion

The tag [single-word-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request) has generated a minor bit of controversy in the past over at ELU, on the basis that such requests are often best answered by something other than a single word.

Especially where English Language Learners are concerned, I think that this tag might be even considered [counterproductive to learning English](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/576/word-meaning-harmful-to-learning). Very often the right equivalent to a foreign word, or the right wording for a particular concept, is *not* a single word at all. English abounds in constructions, and learners of English need to understand when to use a phrase instead of a single word.

Over at ELU the argument can be made that the questioner is an expert and has done enough research to understand that a single word is indeed what they require. But in ELL I'd argue that the questioner might not the best judge of whether a request can be fulfilled by a single word.

In short, I'd like to propose getting rid of single-word-request over here, and replace with something like word-request or phrase-request or word-choice.

Answer (score 10):

I can understand there are languages that use a single word to express a rather complicate concept, but I cannot imagine a learner who, instead of asking for the correct expression to use, would explicitly ask for a single word.

As far as I recall, on EL&U was pointed out that questions tagged [single-word-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request) should not be taken too literally as meaning the OP wants a single word as answer. If that is the case, I think [word-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-request) is a better choice as tag.

Comment: Should we then blacklist single-word-request?

Comment: It is not necessary, if the tag can be merged with another one, and made a synonym.

Comment: Ah yes, of course

Answer (score 7):

I'm a pretty rabid defender of single-word-requests over on ELU, but even I agree that here, the main tag should be [word-requests](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/word-requests), and [single-word-requests](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) should be a synonym. People assign way too much meaning to that "single", and it would be best to just nip that problem in the bud here.

Comment: I agree; nobody has enough rep to suggest a tag synonym yet, so it will have to be a (diamond) moderator.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty valid point. I agree! And I believe "word-request" would come out as more neutral for the purpose.