# Should we be closing single word requests?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-off-topic, close-reasons

I've seen a few questions asking explicitly for *single words*, rather than phrases, which fit a certain description. Today, one popped up in the close queue. I saw [this comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31078/one-word-synonym-follow-up#comment57699_31078):

> Single word requests are off-topic on ELL. We should focus on how to express something naturally, not how to express something within arbitrary game-like limits such as "the expression must be a single orthographic word".

However, this is the first time I've seen such a question closed for this reason. (Open examples: [1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/29846/a-single-word-for-merely-reporting-a-fact) [2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21380/can-i-say-nearly-never-in-a-single-word) [3](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/22441/does-a-word-exist-for-using-a-reservation-on-another-date) [4](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17838/word-for-something-that-is-true-only-at-a-specific-period-in-time) [5](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/312/is-there-a-single-word-for-native-english-speaker)). I voted to close because I agreed with the comment's remarks (we shouldn't be limiting ourselves arbitrarily to one word on this site), but I now find myself rethinking it; likely I will end up rescinding my vote.

Often with these sorts of questions, the answer is *there's just no one single word for this, here are some phrases*, and usually askers will be receptive to this. I've looked at a number of these questions and many parenthetically remark that a short phrase would be OK also, or accept an answer which suggests phrases, etc.

Is this really a reason to close questions? A question which is otherwise fine is now off topic because the asker requested the greatest amount of brevity possible? I don't think this is a reasonable approach, since:

- The question is still perfectly answerable; *there's no single word for X* is a proper answer.
- Learners might not understand English well enough (or may simply have incorrect expectations) to understand that many concepts can't be adequately expressed with a single word in English.
- It's better to put information about the failings of single word expressions in an answer than a close reason. This allows for explanation and suggestion of proper phrasal alternatives, rather than just shutting the question down.
- Single word requests are on topic at ELU; we can migrate there rather than simply closing (assuming that we edit the question first, check for duplicates, etc.).

[This discussion](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125/tag-single-word-request-in-ell) is highly relevant, but about the tag [single-word-request](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-request) rather than the topicality of such questions.

Comment: They are controversial at EL&U as well: *[Word for disrespecting eldest half-sister by referring to her husband as girly-girl-manly-boy though he’s amused but the rest of the family isn’t?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732)* but also *[Suggestion: single word lookups are off topic](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/213)*; 
*[Are word requests allowed?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/354)*; 
*[Requests for coinage](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1216)* …

Comment: … *[Are single word requests always welcomed questions?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1309)*;
*[Is it really so important in English to find a single word to express a single concept?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/3618)*;
*[Against Single Word Requests](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/1654)*;
*[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2160)*; and 
*[Is this the type of single-word request question we should be closing?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2293)*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an excellent question, but you're not focusing on what I think is the main thrust of the comment (which I will put in bold):

> Single word requests are off-topic on ELL. **We should focus on how to express something naturally, not how to express something within arbitrary game-like limits** such as "the expression must be a single orthographic word"

I think the comment as a whole is not meant to say that single-word requests are always off topic, but that the site should discourage the use of a single, obscure word when a shorter phrase would be much better to use in conversation.

As an example, I think a question like this would be on-topic:

> In my native language, we have the word *iyønifix*, which means, roughly, *someone who was once an enemy but is now an ally*. My translation dictionary doesn't have a listing for *iyønifix* – is there a word or idiomatic phrase in English that fits this definition?

Here, the O.P. is clearly an English learner, asking if a word exists in English. I would not vote to close such a question.

However, consider a question like this:

> When I go to restaurants, I see signs by the register that say things like "To Go" or "Carry Out". Is there a single word that could be used instead?

I'm not so fond of this question. There's a reason restaurants hang signs that say "Carry Out" and that cashiers ask, "Is this for here or to go?" – *that's the way we speak the language*.

In the question you cite, the person is asking for a one-word equivalent for *follow up*. There's no reason *follow up* needs to be condensed to one word – it's a common and natural expression, as I think snailplane correctly pointed out.

I think the comment you ask about might have been more accurate had it said:

> Single word requests **like this one** are off-topic on ELL. We should focus on how to express something naturally, not how to express something within arbitrary game-like limits such as "the expression must be a single orthographic word"

In short, I think single-word requests *can* be on-topic on ELL, but it really depends on how the question is framed and what the O.P. is trying to learn.

Comment: I agree with your revision of my comment :-)

Comment: Let's never forget "No", "None such exists" etc is a valid answer to certain questions.

Answer (score 0):

> Single word requests are off-topic on ELL. We should focus on how to express something naturally, not how to express something within arbitrary game-like limits such as "the expression must be a single orthographic word".
>   <sub>[Source](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31078/one-word-synonym-follow-up#comment57699_31078)</sub>

I support this comment:

- to minimise overlap with ELU
- to focus on learning English (I understand requests for a given meaning, but I think one-word requests go beyond general language learning)

Comment: If I could, I'd vote for moving these requests to ELU.

Comment: You can always flag the question and use "other" to request that a moderator move it. I support the comment also, but my question is whether outright closure is the best way to promote its goals while still offering at least some help.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName In "theory", from a user point of view, it'd be friendlier to move the question to ELU than closure.

Comment: I agree completely; this is what I'm getting at. Instead of closing these kinds of questions, we should do something else, like migrate them.

Comment: I chose to leave that open, I think. However, it's sort of like a reverse dictionary lookup, and is likely to be minimally useful to both the OP, and learners in the future.

Comment: I don't think single-word requests are an ELU issue by default. If you are not a native English speaker, and that's the main reason you're seeking a single word, there's a good chance this is the right place to ask.